# displaying table in the right style

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have a problem in displaying the borders of my table correctly ,I work with jsPDF library ,this is the result that I get :

[image]

this is my code that selecet every row and display the data:

```
 function tableToJson(table) {
        var data = [];

        // first row needs to be headers
        var headers = [];
        for (var i=0; i<table.rows[0].cells.length,i<5; i++) {
            headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi,'');
        }
        data.push(headers);
        // go through cells
        for (var i=1; i<table.rows.length;i++) {

            var tableRow = table.rows[i];
            var rowData = {};


            for (var j=0; j<tableRow.cells.length,j<5 ; j++) {

                rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;

            }

            data.push(rowData);

        }       

        return data;
    }


     function callme(){


var table = tableToJson($('#table').get(0));
var doc = new jsPDF('l','pt','letter',true);


$.each(table, function(i, row){
    $.each(row, function(j,cell){
    if(j=="email"){
     doc.cell(1,10,190,20,cell,i);  
    }
    else{
        doc.cell(1,10,100,20,cell,i);
    }

    });
});
```

thanks for help

Comment: Do you want the cells to wrap the content or what is your question? I can recommend you to use the [jspdf-autotable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) library if you want an easier way to work with tables and jspdf.